# How can I get position of mouse click using opencvsharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, get, position, mouse

I want to get the position of a mouse click on an IplImage. I searched for it but I couldn't find anything. There is no source for get mouse position  in c# using openCVsharp methods. So I tried something. When the code is started it is waiting for the waiting time at that time I click with mouse but nothing is happining. And after the waitkey the code stops. Is there a way to get the position of a mouse click on an IplImage?

```
namespace mousedeneeme
{

    class Program
    {           
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IplImage I_clean = Cv.LoadImage("Iclean.tiff", LoadMode.GrayScale);

            String s = Cv.NamedWindow("I_clean image").ToString();

            CvMouseCallback mo = new CvMouseCallback(on_mouse);    

            Cv.SetMouseCallback(s, on_mouse);

            Cv.ShowImage("I_clean image", I_clean);
            Cv.WaitKey(5000);

        }
        public static void on_mouse(MouseEvent me, int x, int y, MouseEvent me7) {

            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is working code

```
CvWindow w = new CvWindow("OpenCV Example") 

w.OnMouseCallback+=new CvMouseCallback(on_mouse);

use += because you are binding event
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


//callback function
void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
    if(evt==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
       printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
     }
}


    int main()
    {

    cvNamedWindow("MyWindow");

    //assigning the callback function for mouse events
    cvSetMouseCallback("MyWindow", mouseEvent, 0);

    //load and display an image
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/Iclean.tiff");
    cvShowImage("MyWindow", img);

    //wait for key press
    cvWaitKey(0);

    //cleaning up
    cvDestroyWindow("MyWindow");
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah thank you.But I need c# code. I saw cpp examples and opencv examples before.But it didn't help me

Comment: check out http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Convert-C-To-C-Download-131126.html it will convert it for you